# SSRS Report Populate same table field values in different columns in Orderly Manner

Tags: reporting-services

I need to fill bank deposit slip, deposit slip in the format of 3 columns for Amount
I want to fill the amount column by column in an orderly manner
But in the table field is the only Amount
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate more? There doesn't seem to be a question here. A format like the following can really help us help you. "This is what I tried, this is what I got, this is what I expect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the row and column that each amount should be in using `RowNumber` functions inside a matrix.

Insert a matrix into the report. Set the columns to be grouped by:

```
=(RowNumber(Nothing) +1) Mod 3
```

Set the rows to be grouped by:

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 3)
```

Here's an example of how the results would look:

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, I will try this one, Thanks a lot

Comment: @PraveenKumarVetrivel did you get a chance to try this out? If it worked, please mark this as answered.

Comment: Hi Steven, Your advice worked, thanks a lot, But I stuck in one another situation, in the same matrix, let say 4 X 5 matrix, in the specific cell say 4 X 1 I want to show Total amount, is it possible?

Comment: What would be the scope of the subtotal? All the values? Just the column? Is a regular `Sum()` not working for you?